# How do I prove that $2\sin(x)>x$ for every $0<x<\pi/2\,$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I managed to prove that $\bigl|e^{2 \pi  ki/n}-1\bigr|=2\sin(\pi k/n)$, I think that using the above it is possible to prove that $2\sin(x)>x$ but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format your question.

Answer (score 2):

We work on $[0, \pi / 2]$.

Derive $f:x\mapsto 2 \sin x - x$. You get $f':x\mapsto 2\cos x -1$, and $2\cos x \geqslant 1$ is equivalent to $x\leqslant \pi / 3$, so $f$ is increasing on $[0,\pi / 3]$ and decreasing on $[\pi / 3, \pi / 2]$. And $f(0) = 0$, and $f(\pi / 2) >0$.

So for all $x\in ]0, \pi / 2[$, $2\sin x \geqslant x$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
Could you clarify what you mean by this f:x↦2sinx−x ?

Comment: As I want to show $2 \sin x -x$ is positive on an interval, it's the same to show that the function defined by $f(x) = 2 \sin x -x$ is positive on this interval. $f:x\mapsto 2\sin x -x$ is just another way to write the definition of $f$.